# How to integrate jquery.fileupload-rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-file-upload

I am trying to integrate the following gem: https://rubygems.org/gems/jquery.fileupload-rails but it became a mission impossible. I am trying for last two days and it simply doesn't want to load jquery.fileupload-rails javascript.

I tried this tutorials:

railscasts.com/episodes/381-jquery-file-upload?view=asciicast
5minutenpause.com/blog/2013/09/04/multiple-file-upload-with-jquery-rails-4-and-paperclip/

This is my application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= jquery.fileupload/basic
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Gemfile.lock:

```
jquery-rails (3.1.2)
jquery-ui-rails (5.0.2)
jquery.fileupload-rails (1.11.0)
```

I have tried many combinations and it doesn't work. How to make it work?

Comment: The gem they're using in your 2nd example is `jquery-fileupload-rails`, not `jquery.fileupload-rails`.  There is no `basic.js` in the gem you installed, so you probably can't `require` it.

Comment: Try following the instructions at the gem you have installed, [at this link](https://github.com/semaperepelitsa/jquery.fileupload-rails).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a line to your Gemfile.

gem 'jquery.fileupload-rails'

Now you can require the javascript library in application.js:

//= require jquery.fileupload

[doc](https://github.com/semaperepelitsa/jquery.fileupload-rails)

[demo](https://github.com/semaperepelitsa/jquery.fileupload-rails/tree/master/demo)